# django messages not displaying

Tags: python, django, django-messages

If i post the message to the webapp, i can find it if i log in as a django super user and check in the backend using the django admin pannel but they are not displaying on my website.. I'll put up screengrabs of all the related code.

[these are my django imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEefM.png)

[This is the room view code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXUDV.png)

[This is the room template html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPae7.png)

[This is how it is outputting to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4Gfg.png)

I think i should also mention I'm following a tutorial by Traversy media and have sent 2 days trying to figure this out.

I thought maybe it was typing errors or a mistake in my loops but i re-wrote that code multiple times now

Comment: Please post the code as text not screenshot.